# inserting multiple columns from form to mysql

Tags: php

**this is my html form**

---

```
<div id="customcopies">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Member Name:</th>
            <th>Relation with head of the family:</th>
            <th>Date of Birth:</th>
            <th>Blood Group:</th>
            <th>Education:</th>
            <th>Business / Employee:</th>
            <th>Married / Un-Married:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="m_name_1" name="m_name[]"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="m_relation_1" name="m_relation[]"/></td>
            <td><input type="date" class="form-control" id="m_dob_1" name="m_dob[]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="m_bgroup_1" name="m_bgroup[]"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="m_education_1" name="m_education[]"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="m_business_1" name="m_business[]"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="m_married_1" name="m_married[]"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

---

**insert.php**

---

```
$insert1 =$db->prepare("INSERT INTO members (user_id, m_name, m_relation, m_dob, m_bgroup, m_education, m_business, m_married)VALUES (:us, :m_name, :m_relation, :m_dob, :m_bgroup, :m_education, :m_business, :m_married)");

$insert1->bindParam(":us", $us);
$insert1->bindParam(":m_name", $m_name);
$insert1->bindParam(":m_relation", $m_relation);
$insert1->bindParam(":m_dob", $m_dob);
$insert1->bindParam(":m_bgroup", $m_bgroup);
$insert1->bindParam(":m_education", $m_education);
$insert1->bindParam(":m_business", $m_business);
$insert1->bindParam(":m_married", $m_married);
$insert1->execute();
```

I have a jquery code by which I can add same  table multiple times...and after filling out the form the last column is only getting inserted into database 
for example:
1st members details 
2nd members details
3rd members details

only the 3rd members details ....is getting inserted

Comment: You are inserting a user_id. Isn't that autogenerated by your database?

Comment: yes its auto incremented

Comment: Try : $insert1 =$db->prepare("INSERT INTO members (user_id, m_name, m_relation, m_dob, m_bgroup, m_education, m_business, m_married)VALUES (null, :m_name, :m_relation, :m_dob, :m_bgroup, :m_education, :m_business, :m_married)");   And remove $insert1->bindParam(":us", $us);

Comment: not working by removing this($insert1->bindParam(":us", $us);) tooo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have form tags around the form in order to send it to insert.php.  I'm unsure why you are making the names of your input arrays though.  Are you having multiples of the same input name?  If you do have multiples of the same name and have an array then you need to use a for loop to go through each array and insert them into the database.  If you have the same amount of values in each input array then it'll be easier.

```
<div id="customcopies">
<form action='insert.php' method='post'>
  <table>
   <tr>
     <th>Member Name:</th>
     <th>Relation with head of the family:</th>
     <th>Date of Birth:</th>
     <th>Blood Group:</th>
     <th>Education:</th>
     <th>Business / Employee:</th>
     <th>Married / Un-Married:</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="m_name_1" name="m_name[]"/></td>

     <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="m_relation_1" name="m_relation[]"/></td>

     <td><input type="date" class="form-control" id="m_dob_1" name="m_dob[]"></td>

     <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="m_bgroup_1" name="m_bgroup[]"/></td>

     <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="m_education_1" name="m_education[]"/></td>

     <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="m_business_1" name="m_business[]"/></td>

     <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="m_married_1" name="m_married[]"/></td>
   </tr>                                                               
  </table>  
</form>  
</div>
```

And now we need to insert each value into the database.  I am assuming that there are the same amount of values in each array.  I'm not sure where $us is coming from?

```
$us=$_SESSION['userid']; // THIS IS ASSUMING HOW TO GET THE USERID B/C YOU DIDN'T SAY HOW.
$m_name=$_POST['m_name'];
$m_relation=$_POST['m_relation'];
$m_dob=$_POST['m_dob'];
$m_bgroup=$_POST['m_bgroup'];
$m_education=$_POST['m_education'];
$m_business=$_POST['m_business'];
$m_married=$_POST['m_married'];

$arrayCount=count($m_name); //THIS WILL TELL FOR LOOP HOW MANY TIMES TO LOOP.

for (i=1; i<=$arrayCount; i++) {
  $num=$i-1;

  $insert1 =$db->prepare("INSERT INTO members (user_id, m_name, m_relation, m_dob, m_bgroup, m_education, m_business, m_married)VALUES (:us, :m_name, :m_relation, :m_dob, :m_bgroup, :m_education, :m_business, :m_married)");

  $insert1->bindParam(":us", $us);
  $insert1->bindParam(":m_name", $m_name[$num]);
  $insert1->bindParam(":m_relation", $m_relation[$num]);
  $insert1->bindParam(":m_dob", $m_dob[$num]);
  $insert1->bindParam(":m_bgroup", $m_bgroup[$num]);
  $insert1->bindParam(":m_education", $m_education[$num]);
  $insert1->bindParam(":m_business", $m_business[$num]);
  $insert1->bindParam(":m_married", $m_married[$num]);
  $insert1->execute();
}
```

Let me know if this isn't what you were talking about and I'll edit it to fit your needs.

Comment: Great!  Don't forget to check the answer as correct. :-)